# Android: IPhonish Tabs but displayed at the top

Tags: android

I like this IPhonish tab but I can't figure out how to make it display at the top instead of at the bottom.

http://bakhtiyor.com/2009/10/iphonish-tabs/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:checkedButton="@+id/first" android:id="@+id/states">
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/first" android:background="@drawable/button_radio"
        android:width="80dip" android:height="70dip" />
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/second" android:background="@drawable/button_radio"
        android:width="80dip" android:height="70dip" />
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/third" android:background="@drawable/button_radio"
        android:width="80dip" android:height="70dip" />
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/fourth" android:background="@drawable/button_radio"
        android:width="80dip" android:height="70dip" />
    </RadioGroup>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1" android:padding="20dip" android:background="#fff"/>
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0" android:visibility="gone" />
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Just two comments:

- iPhone tabs sucks... no, sorry, I meant: iPhone tabs SUCKS. In fact, tabs sucks.
- Read about UI basis before trying to do things like this. As you saw, you just had to change the order of the LinearLayouts children.

Comment: why do you seem to be saying all tabs suck? can you elaborate? I have used tabs in my apps, not like this approach, but simply using the TabHost and TabWidget as provided by Android. I like the look of the iPhone tabs too, and I personally think tabs have their place if it helps the UI flow.